# Promises on sequelize

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, sequelize.js

This is more of a general question.
From my understanding a promise is an async call and that is why we define the THEN in sequelize after a method so we wait for a response.

My question is the following, when requesting data from my db with methods like findAll or findByPk I always use a .then(). But when using data manipulating methods like create() or update(), I have tested them with .then() and without and can see no difference. When should I use the .then() and when should I not and why?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, dou you want to do something after the database operation or you just don't care about the result? My guess is that you care about the result in any case (read or write), then use `.then()` and `.catch()` or the modern style if your runtime supports it: `try`/`catch` with `async`/`await`

Comment: Hi, well i mean in this case since im just creating or updating a product i would simply be redirecting to a view. In which case i have tried using .then and not using it and the result has been the same.. hence my doubt as to why

Comment: If you don't use `.then()`, you redirect to the view whatever the result is. You may not have a database connected at all, the result would be the same. I doubt this is the behavior you want, that's why I'm saying you care about the result.